# enumerateObjectsUsingBlock and completion together

Tags: ios, objective-c, completionhandler

I have situation where I am iterating my array objects using enumerateObjectsUsingBlock, and I need to wait for a completion in the iteration then it should execute further code, how can I achieve this, or if any alternate I should use, below is my code

```
[arrPendingQueue enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PendingQueues *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

       //Fetch static google map based on coordinates
       [self generateMapImage:obj.postObj completion:^(UIImage *image) {
           NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES).firstObject stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"camera"];

          NSString *resultPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"map_%f.jpg",[[Constants getSystemDateInLocalTimeZone] timeIntervalSince1970]]];

          [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:resultPath contents:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) attributes:nil];

          postObj.imagepath = [@"camera" stringByAppendingPathComponent:[resultPath lastPathComponent]];

          [DataManager saveObject:postObj];                                             
       }];

       //After the completion I want to upload the data here to server

});
```

Basically, I am trying to download static google map from coordinate in function `generateMapImage` and I want the loop to wait till completion called..

For that I tried to use `dispatch_semaphore_create` like

```
[arrPendingQueue enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PendingQueues *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
     dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

     [self generateMapImage:obj.postObj completion:^(UIImage *image) {

         dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);                                    
     }];

     dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

});
```

But it doesn't work it doesn't wait, and executes the code before completion completed.

How to solve, please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Use Custom `NSOperation` subclass

Comment: Do you want to wait for the completion of a single operation in each step or do you want to wait for the completion of all operations?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Completion of a single operation in each step.

Comment: @SahebRoy How can NSOperation help, can give more light into it, it will still have to wait for the execution..

Comment: Hmmm, should work with the semaphore. Are you sure that the actual operation is not completed? However, why don't you move the code to wait into the completion block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To queue up execution of a series of a blocks, you can simply start the new block in the completion handler of the old block:

```
NSEnumerator *objectEnum = [arrPendingQueue objectEnumerator];
__block void (^handler) ();
handler = ^(UIImage *image)
{
   // Handle image
   object = [objectEnum nextObject];
   if( object == nil )
   {
     // completion of all operations
   }
   else 
   {
     // Start next operation
     [self generateMapImage:object.postObj completion:handler];
   }                                    
 };
 [self generateMapImage:obj.postObj completion:handler];
}
```

A more classical or elegant way would be to use a [Y-combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus). But it is not necessary. Just keep in mind, that local scope variables are cleaned up when losing their scope. `handler` is not retained. So maybe you have to put it into an ivar.

However, I see `-generateMapImage:completion` is written by you. I cannot see the content, but if you do a async call there and you can set the queue used for the call, simply set it to a serial queue. In such a case your requests will be executed serial automatically.